# Map reduce without hadoop

Tags: mapreduce

I am new to Map reduce program.I want to know if I can run map reduce program as a normal java program without using Hadoop. What all libraries should I include?Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but in that you need to write each end every code block starting from map-->SS-->Reduce. Tobe very simple hadoop is a framework built on provides lot API to run the mapreduce job. It will take care of passing the input from file, Suffle and sort and then reduce function. you just need to understand the various API of haddop and the flow of data thats it.